# TornadoFx FXTask OutOfMemoryError

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

So i have an interesting piece of code and i run into an OutOfMemoryError.

So my problem is that i am creating inside my searchThread new threads which are searching again. This abviously creates an OutOfMemoryError but i wannted to use TornadoFX code only to solve that without any luck.

```
searchThread = runAsync {
    while (!searchThread.isCancelled) {
            runAsync {
                // Searching for Sth
            } ui {
                // Updating UI 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i get, if runAsync inside my search thread, is still running so i can skip the creation of an new thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing where is creating new tasks in a tight loop, so obviously you'll run out of memory. The call for the nested `runAsync` will not wait, just execute again until the condition is false.

Remove the inner `runAsync` and just do whatever you want to do, then call `runLater` if you want to update something on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem. Your goal is to have only one search thread that doesn't get called if it is already running. Like Edvin said, looping the calling of async threads is really really bad. Not to mention, the nested threads might not even have a kill condition. This would be a simple solution but wouldn't this make more sense?:

```
val searchTask: Task<YourReturnType>? = null
private fun search() {
   if(searchTask?.isRunning != true) {
      searchTask = runAsync {
         //Do your search thread things
      } ui { result ->
         //do things with your UI based on your result
      }
   }
}
```

Similarly, if you want to have an old running search thread be replaced by a new one instead, you could try something like:

```
val searchTask: Task<YourReturnType>? = null
private fun search() {
   if(searchTask?.isRunning == true) {
      searchTask?.cancel()
      //You should probably do something to check if the cancel succeeded.
   }
   searchTask = runAsync {
      //Do your search thread things
   } ui { result ->
      //do things with your UI based on your result
   }
}
```